# Cannot pass a variable given from url to route's callback function and redirect issue

Tags: python, flask

## Flask app.py

```
@app.route( '/' ) 
@app.route( '/<page>' ) 
def index( page ): 

# use the variable form template for displaying 
counter = '''<center> 
                <table bgcolor=black bordercolor=orangered> 
                td><font size=3 color=lime> Αριθμός Επισκεπτών: </font></td> 
<td><a href="{{ url_for( '/log', page='%s' ) }}"><font size=3 color=plum> %d </font></a></td> 
                                </table> 
                        ''' % (page, pagehit) 

if page != 'index.html': 
    pdata = redirect( 'http://superhost.gr/cgi-bin/' + page ) 
    return pdata
```

## Template index.html

```
<div align=right> 
        <a href="{{ url_for( '/', page='some_value' ) }}">        <img src="/static/images/π.gif"> </a> 
</div> 

<a href="{{ url_for( '/', page='another_value' ) }}">        <img src="/static/images/download.gif"></a>
```

All I want to do is when the user clicks on the images within the html tamplate, to pass those variables value to '/' route so to perform some action with those values

## The error iam receiving is this:

```
builtins.TypeError 
TypeError: index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'page'
```

I mean I do have  declared in route and also do  have 'page' as variable to the callback function, why can't it see it?

2. Also about the redirect function I am using... is there a way to get back the HTML response of running that cgi-script and then add another HTML value to that response? I used subprocess and Response but they weren't able to deliver the content back the pdata variable for display. 
   What I actually want to do among other things is from within my flask app script to try to run and get the response back of a cgi-script

I just now tried this:

```
@app.route( '/' )
@app.route( '/<page>' )
def index( page='index.html' ):
```

but iam getting:

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint '/' with values ['page']. Did you mean 'log' instead?
```

I want 'page' variable to have a default value of 'index.html' but i wonder why cant it run it. Also 'page=None' doesn't work either as well.

Comment: I think the problem could be the very first line - that defines the `/` route for this function too. Now, try using `def index(page=None)` to add a default value - that might work. But what will definitively work is splitting that up into two functions, one `def index()` that calls `def index2(page)` with the default value for page.

Comment: the 1st  solution did not work.please correct my code attempt because ctrl-k does not work in comments. @app.route( '/' )
def index( ):
 index2( page )

@app.route( '/<page>' )
def index2( page ):  gives me NameError: name 'page' is not defined. Ho can i post code within comments properly? ven 4 spaces wont do it.

Comment: Could you please show me your suggestion that will definately work with code?